# Communication between items in list with itemrenderer

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer

For a list am having 3 items. I have implemented the list with `itemrenderer`. In the itemrenderer,i have a label and an image,on selecting an item,the images in other two items should change. so how can i achieve this behavior .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of Flex are you using?

Comment: The label and image are bound to a model right? You just need to change the appropriate model's 'image' attributes. This is fairly similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870771/how-to-select-an-object-in-a-flex-hgroup/14911747#14911747

Comment: Can you provide some working code?

Comment: I am having no idea regarding that @RajaJaganathan. But i want is there any possibility???

Comment: Am using 4.6 @user3277549